# How to handle event in outlook add-in?

Tags: events, event-handling, outlook, outlook-addin

It is work only one time, than event handler not work.I do not understand why?

```cs
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    var folder = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.DefaultStore.
                   GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
    foreach(Outlook.TaskItem item in folder.Items) {
        item.BeforeDelete += BeforeDelete;
        item.Save();
    }
}

private void BeforeDelete(object item, ref bool cancel) {
    MessageBox.Show("Удалено");
    // Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item); must I do It?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The object that raises the event must be alive to raise the events. In you case you are setting an event sync on a local variable that gets garbage collected and hence does not raise the events anymore. Keep the object referenced on the global (class) level. It your case, it needs to be a list of TaskItem objects.

That being said, do not ever set event sinks on *all* items in a folder. You will kill Outlook. Since the user needs to select an item before attempting to delete it, process Explorer.SelectionChange event, clear the list of items, then set up event sinks on the items from the Explorer.Selection collection